# How Do I Calculate Proportions Of Data Subsets?

Tags: r, statistics, rstudio, data-analysis

I've got some code below that I need help with. I'm asking for my data science coursera class "Are Americans Financial Satisfaction Affected By The Previous Year's Annual S&P500 Gain/Loss?". I'm trying to plot a graph with the amount of observations that are either Satisfied or More Or Less Satisfied, against the entire population (a proportion) as the y axis, and the `"PercentChange"` as the x-axis. I posted the entire code further down, in case it was necessary to understand what I'm trying to do. All of these observations are in the same table `"finalResults"` and they are listed under a variable column that is categorical, named `"FinancialSatisfaction"`. I'm not sure where to go from here, but the big problem I'm having is how to calculate the proportions based on `"PercentChange"` in the final results table. Right below is what I had tried, but it is way off. I need to filter the satisfaction proportions by year, as the x-axis will be each year's percentage change. Help is greatly appreciated, I am nowhere near knowledgeable enough about R to figure this out.

```
satisfied <- subset(finalResults, FinancialSatisfaction == "Satisfied")
moreorless <- subset(finalResults, FinancialSatisfaction == "More Or Less")
notatall <- subset(finalResults, FinancialSatisfaction == "Not At All")

myProportion = (satisfied + moreorless) / 29205
```

#### FULL CODE:

```
require(Quandl)
require(lubridate)
require(zoo)
require(xts)

myGSS <- load(url("http://bit.ly/dasi_gss_data"))

year <- gss$year
finSat <- gss$satfin

relativeTable <- data.frame(year, finSat)
relativeTable <- subset(relativeTable, year > "1988" & !is.na(finSat))


spReturns <- Quandl("SANDP/ANNRETS", trim_start="1970-01-11", 
                    trim_end="2012-12-31", authcode="nwy3a_Gmd7TSS9fVirxT", 
                    collapse="annual")

percentChange <- spReturns$"Total Return Change"

spReturns$"Year Ending" <- format((spReturns$"Year Ending"), "%Y")
spReturns$"Year Ending" <- as.numeric(spReturns$"Year Ending")
spReturns$"Year Ending" <- spReturns[,1] + 1 #the following year

combined <- merge(relativeTable, spReturns, by.x = "year", by.y = "Year Ending")
names(combined)[6] <- "percentChange"

finalResults <- data.frame(combined$year, combined$finSat, combined$percentChange)
names(finalResults)[1] <- "Year"
names(finalResults)[2] <- "FinancialSatisfaction"
names(finalResults)[3] <- "PercentChange"
finalResults$PercentChange <- finalResults$PercentChange * 100

satisfied <- subset(finalResults, FinancialSatisfaction == "Satisfied")
moreorless <- subset(finalResults, FinancialSatisfaction == "More Or Less")
notatall <- subset(finalResults, FinancialSatisfaction == "Not At All")

myProportion <- (satisfied + moreorless) / 29205
```

Comment: `prop.table` maybe?  Also, you should look at `data.table::setnames`, you're making a lot of copies in your code.

Comment: I have to calculate the proportion of "Satisfied" and "More Or Less" compared to the total number of observations for year "X", starting at 1989. After computing that for each year, I need to place them in a column at the end of the dataset similar to what we see with "PercentChange". What's the most efficient way to do this? Sorry I'm an R noob.

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
myProportion = (satisfied + moreorless) / 29205
```

`satisfied` and `moreorless` are `data.frame`s, so your result is also a DF; you probably want something like

```
myProporition <- mean(finalResults$FinancialSatisfaction == "Satisfied" | finalResults$FinancialSatisfaction == "More or Less")
```

Comment: I have to calculate the proportion of "Satisfied" and "More Or Less" compared to the total number of observations for year "X", starting at 1989. After computing that for each year, I need to place them in a column at the end of the dataset similar to what we see with "PercentChange". What's the most efficient way to do this? Sorry I'm an R noob.

Answer (score 0):

This solution might help:

```
satisfied <- subset(finalResults, FinancialSatisfaction == "Satisfied")
moreorless <- subset(finalResults, FinancialSatisfaction == "More Or Less")
notatall <- subset(finalResults, FinancialSatisfaction == "Not At All")

myProportion = (nrow(satisfied) + nrow(moreorless)) / nrow(finalResults)
```